# Why function don't change a var

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter, global

I tired to change the expression variable within a function. And i used the global word in the function but it still don't working. This is a tkinter porblem. Please help.

Here is the part of the code

```
expression = ''

sum_label = Label(root, text=expression, bg='#D3D3D3', padx=113, pady=14)
sum_label.place(x=20, y=10)


#Numbers
def press(num):
    global expression
    expression += str(num)
    print(num)
```

The press function just for a few button but it's work because if i print the num then it's working perfectly. But the text of the label isn't changing.

Comment: The procedure is never run. Show the simplest program that exhibits the problem.

Comment: When the Label is created, `expression` is a blank string.  Updating `expression` afterwards will not affect the existing Label object.

Comment: `Label` only gets the *value* of `expression`; it doesn't know anything about the variable, let alone changes to what the variable refers to later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the label to be *linked* to a mutable value, you need to  specify a `StringVar` object with the `textvariable` argument, not an immutable `str` via the `text` argument.

```
expression = StringVar()

sum_label = Label(root, textvariable=expression, bg='#D3D3D3', padx=113, pady=14)
sum_label.place(x=20, y=10)


def press(num):
    expression.set(expression.get() + str(num))
    print(num)
```

Note that `press` does not need to declare `expression` as a global, because you never assign to the name `expression`. You only use the global's `get` and `set` methods to interact with the `StringVar` instance bound to the name.

See https://tkdocs.com/shipman/control-variables.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Label, you set the value of the expression as an empty string, and you can't expect it to change after creating the Label with an empty string.So it is better to consider these changes before creating the Label object

Comment: Could you give an example?